# Cortex M0 - Defining an interrupt routine in assembly

Tags: arm, interrupts, assembly

For a project I have some code that needs to be written in assembly due to precise timing requirements. I'd ideally like to implement my code in a timer interrupt routine. Right now, in C++ I can define an ISR as such:

```
extern "C" void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
//code here
}
```

I'm using an STM32F030 chip, which from the datasheet shows that the Timer3 IRQ address is 0x00000080. My understanding is that there is an address stored at this location that marks the start of the interrupt handler.

How do I change the address at the above entry to point to the start address of my assembly code so that I can handle the interrupt in assembly? I know I can technically put inline assembly within the C function above, but there must be a way to handle the interrupt entirely in assembly.

I should note that I'm using the GNU ARM toolchain

Comment: You don't. Interrupt vectors are very small, usually just a jump to the actual routine, whatever you put in there probably won't fit in the vector, which is why you just assign addresses to the function in the vectors.

Comment: @RonBeyer that's exactly my question though - how do I assign addresses to the function in the vectors? Apologies if my question wasn't clear

Comment: You must already have startup code (the only .s file in your project) that has the vector table. So you just define a function with that name and your routine will get called. It does not matter if it is a C or assembly routine as long as the linker finds it by name. Under the hood, it is already weakly bound to a catch-all error interrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I change the address at the above entry to point to the start address of my assembly code so that I can handle the interrupt in assembly?

Asssuming default startup, just declare the function with the correct name in assembler:

```
.syntax unified
.thumb
.arch armv6m
.text

.global TIM3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_func
TIM3_IRQHandler:
  BX LR
.end
```

Note: This example will deadlock (read: infinitely tail-chain), since the timer flags are not resetted properly.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have to do in C is give the function a specific name, then your project is using [weak binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) to select the interrupt handler. In this case, all you need to do is create an assembly function with the correct symbol name. With EABI, this should be the same as the C function name. Otherwise, you may need to add an underscore to the front of the name (i.e. _TIM3_IRQHandler). You can search the linker map file after compilation to see what your C function is called in the symbol table.

Don't forget to clear the interrupt flag in the peripheral!

If you want to know how all this works: The linker is responsible for storing data and code in specific addresses. The location of the interrupt vectors is in the linker script, which (depending on the toolchain) may be part of your project or may be auto-generated. Normally an assembly section will be defined just for the vectors.

The values stored in the interrupt vectors will come from a C or assembly file. If you're using an IDE, look for default files generated with your IDE project. Usually these things are MCU-specific, so I don't think it should be an actual part of GCC.

In any case, once you find the actual interrupt vector list (possibly an array of function pointers), you'll probably see a reference to a default handler. That default handler will be defined with weak binding through a #pragma or **attribute**, and it's what gets replaced when you define your own function. If you want to give your ISR an arbitrary name, you can put its address directly into the vector list. I don't recommend this; it's not good to modify vendor-provided files unless you need to.